# Vuex: How to wait for action to finish?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to implement a login method. My code for it is :

```
login() {
  let user = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  };

  this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', user)
  console.log(this.$store.getters['auth/getAuthError'])
},
```

Where I reach the store and dispatch the login action.

the action in the store looks like this:

```
login(vuexContext, user) {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user/login', user)
        .then(res => {
            vuexContext.commit('setToken', res.data.token)
            vuexContext.commit('setUser', res.data, {root: true})
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
            Cookie.set('token', res.data.token )
            this.$router.push('/')
        }).catch(err => {
            vuexContext.commit('setAuthError', err.response.data)
        })
    },
```

In the catch block, if an error happens, I update the state and set `authError` property to the error i get.

My problem is that, in the login method, the `console.log` statement is executed before the action is actually finished so that the `authError` property is the state has not been set yet. 
How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Your `action` is *returning* a `promise` so you can *console* after the
>   promise has been resolved in `then()` block.

```
login() {
  let user = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  };

  this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', user).then(() => {
   console.log(this.$store.getters['auth/getAuthError'])
   // this.$router.push('/') // Also, its better to invoke router's method from a component than in a store file, anyway reference of a component may not be defined in the store file till you explicity pass it
  })
},
```

> OR, you can make *login* an `async` function & `wait` for the `action` till *promise*
>   returned by action has been *resolved*

```
async login() {
  let user = {
    email: this.email,
    password: this.password
  };

  await this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', user)
  console.log(this.$store.getters['auth/getAuthError'])
},
```

Comment: if we are using your first example (.then on action), since the action have a promise in it (axios) the .then in the component will be executed before the data is in the state right ?

Comment: nvm i returned the promise from the action and the .then worked in component

Answer (score 2):

You can use **async-await** instead of **Promise.then**. But my suggestion is not to use Axios inside the store. Call Axios inside the login method and then call the store. Something like this:

```
methods: {
    async login() {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user/login', this.user);
            this.$store.dispatch('auth/login', result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you just need to set the Object in your store.

Comment: Why not user axios in store ?

Comment: Its not a good coding practice. In fundamentals of Programming, we have a design principle known as Separation of Concern which says a file/function should handle only one role. In your case, Vuex is managing the store as well as API.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but @ShubhamSharma answer isn't right. According to flux concept, stores should manage global state, as well deal with side effects, so view doesn't. This helps to avoid bugs and write less code. 

TLDR: Put your requests in store actions, side effects should be handled in there.